# Jetbrains xodus broken dependencies

Tags: xodus

Recently, I faced with some build errors in my project which is using [JetBrains/xodus](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus) v1.2.3. In project's pom.xml I have such dependecy

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
  <artifactId>xodus-environment</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But during build process I've faced with such error:

```
[ERROR] Version conflict for artifact org.jetbrains:annotations, selected 13.0, dependencies require 15.0
```

So I've checked dependency tree in IDEA. I was wondered to see [such dependency tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctAU9.png)

As you can see library `org.jetbrains.xodus:xodus-environment` has several dependencies on `org.jetbrains:annotations` first one is 13.0 and another one is 15.0.

So I solved problem with such configuration

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.51</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
  <artifactId>xodus-environment</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But I think there is better way to solve this problem or maybe it is bug in xodus library

Comment: Can you please try to depend your project on the same Kotlin version as Xodus depends on, 1.2.21? would it help?

Comment: No, it didn't help. I added `kotlin-stdlib` `1.2.21` dependency and removed all exclusions and received the same error. P.S. Sorry for late response :)